# "Things which are hung/mounted on wall" in a single word?

Tags: single-word-requests, hypernyms

Is there an umbrella term for things like:

- wall clock
- wall-mounted TV
- tapestry

I'm looking for a single, or at most two words for naming a concept in a programming project.

Comment: In a programming project, what about "const static" ;-)

Comment: Lets pray they stay hung in their place, so that the program doesn't hang =)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is "Hanging" not sufficient?
Or perhaps "Adornment"?

Comment: Thanks, I went with ``Hanging`` (liked the shortness) and the code is live now!

Comment: We often use "a hanging", or for more than one, "hangings" for those things hanging on a wall.

Answer (score 2):

How about *wall-mountables*? Yes I know it's not really a noun but sometimes it's OK to use an invented word in programming, right?

Comment: Yes, programming is all about naming and coining. At first I wrote "wallmounted" as a stub, but "hanging" worked better for me.

Comment: 'Hangable' is another way you could express it as a property of an object.

Answer (score 0):

The best option I can think of is ***wall ornament***, but I don't think it really applies to tapestry unless it's an extraordinary tapestry…

Answer (score 0):

**fixture**

> a piece of equipment or furniture that is fixed in position in a building <strike>or vehicle</strike>.

Comment: This does not answer the question, which had to do with "naming a concept in a programming project".

Comment: The question was "Is there an umbrella term for things like..." which I answered. As this is the English stack exchange, why would lack of any relation to a programming project decrease the value of my answer? I'm confused as to why you (presumably) think that the other answers answer the question when the accepted answer didn't relate to programming any more than mine (which isn't a bad thing). As someone who arrived at this page on a programming project on my own with the word "fixture" in mind, I made it my answer and even used it in my program.

Comment: Your answer came up in the review queue due to its brevity and lack of context and supporting references. I am making no comment about the other answers here. I suggest you take the tour about  ["How to write  a good answer"](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) BTW, not my downvote.

Comment: This question was posted some six years ago, and unfortunately none of the answers you see here actually conform to present site standards, so please do not take them as a something to imitate. I know that in other forums and SE sites brevity is appreciated; however, here the reverse is true.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Do you think I should delete my answer?

Comment: My suggestion would be to flesh out your answer with a link to the source for your definiton as well as the attribution for the source. In addition, a few words about how this could apply to computing would help. As it stands, the definition looks like it only applies to buildings or vehicles.,-) Please look at highly rated answers for more recent posts for examples.